# Getting error "cannot find or load main class HelloWorld"

Tags: java

I have this simple code:

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("HelloWorld");
    }
}
```

And the filename HelloWorld.java

In command prompt, I type in:

```
javac HelloWorld.java

java HelloWorld
```

(same directory)

I am getting the error: "cannot find or load main class HelloWorld"

I'm sure it has nothing to do with improper installation because I reinstalled jdk and jre twice.

**Edit:**

This was working before, and the next day, no change of code, directory, or anything, its started giving an error.

Comment: What's the output of `javac -version`?

Comment: Did you confirm no errors in the output of `javac HelloWorld.java`?

Comment: That's one suspicious upvote

Comment: I hope he would have reported errors... :) My guess is that javac is not actually javac...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get this behaviour if you have an incorrect / inappropriate setting of the CLASSPATH environment variable; e.g. the current directory isn't on the classpath.  (It is by default ... )

Try this:

```
java -classpath . HelloWorld
```

Assuming that works ... the problem is your understanding of the concept of the "classpath". This is explained well by the Oracle documentation:

- The [java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) & [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) command documentation ... particular the -classpath argument
- [Setting the Classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).
- [The Java Tutorial - PATH and CLASSPATH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

Comment: Did you read the references in my answer?  Do that and you should be able to understand why it worked.  Hint: if it worked, you can infer that the CLASSPATH environment variable must have been wrong.

Answer (score 3):

try:
`java -cp "C:\WhatEverDirectoryYourFileIsIn" HelloWorld`

Answer (score -8):

In CMD, instead of typing:

```
java HelloWorld
```

Try typing:

```
java HelloWorld.class
```

Comment: To specify the file extension. Because javac will place HelloWorld.class in the same directory of HelloWorld.java. Therefore you have to specify the file extension so that CMD knows you want to run HelloWorld.class, not HelloWorld.java. Without the file extensions, there are two files named HelloWorld. You have to specify which one

Comment: You know, it doesn't have to be some complex solution. A lot of times something just turns out to be some stupid little mistake that you didn't even realize you made.

Comment: So don't give me crap for trying to help. @uraimo

Comment: Nicholas it **doesn't** work if you use the extension. It never did, it's a common java beginner mistake using the `.class`. The `java` launcher expect that you give him the *fully qualified class name*, that's just the `package` of your class `+` the name of the Class (what he has after public class). In this case he has no package, so `HelloWorld` is enough. No one is giving you crap, instead of trying to explain a wrong answer, start wondering if it's correct and edit it when you find out it's wrong. Check the other two answers, THOSE could be correct, not this one.

Comment: @NicholasGreene - Downvoting is not "giving you crap".  Rather it is the preferred way of telling you ... and more importantly, other readers ... that this is a bad answer.  In this case, it is bad because it is unequivocally incorrect.  I suggest that you just delete your Answer, and get back the rep points.

Comment: Whatever, I never have to deal with this because I use an IDE.